# FileNotFoundError in python using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Its just a simple problem I face. I m trying to read my csv file in jupyter notebook. It shows me an error saying the FileNotFoundError  . I couldnt find the apt solutions for this anywhere. Please helpme in getting rid of this error and read the csv file. thanks in advance

The error is

```
 FileNotFoundError
 Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-16-3b1f95fc5c0b> in <module>()
  ----> 1 dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\seminar\totaldata.csv')
  2 dataset.head()

      ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
      parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, 
    index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, 
    converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, 
    nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, 
        skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, 
     keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, 
    compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, 
    escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, 
  error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, 
     delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
         677 
      --> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
       679 
        680     parser_f.__name__ = name

     ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
      _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
      438 
          439     # Create the parser.
      --> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
   441 
    442     if chunksize or iterator:

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, 
   engine, **kwds)
          785             self.options['has_index_names'] = 
   kwds['has_index_names']
       786 
      --> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
         788 
       789     def close(self):

        ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in 
    _make_engine(self, engine)
      1012     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
        1013         if engine == 'c':
 -> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, 
 **self.options)
      1015         else:
   1016             if engine == 'python':

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, 
      src, **kwds)
       1706         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
       1707 
   -> 1708         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
      1709 
     1710         passed_names = self.names is None

 pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

      pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in 
 pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()
```

FileNotFoundError: File b'D:\seminar\totaldata.csv' does not exist

```
    dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\seminar\totaldata.csv')  
    dataset.head()
```

Comment: Please show the content of D:\seminar\, preferably via `os.listdir('D:\seminar\')`

Comment: @Slam don't you need a raw string for the backslashes to work as expected?

Comment: This may be a backslash issue. Try `pd.read_csv(r'D:\seminar\totaldata.csv')`  instead to use a raw string literal.

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia Or use the proper type of directory separator (`/`) and let Python convert them to the Bad character in the background???

Comment: @luke : when i tried using raw string it shows : UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b29b65e90849> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset = pd.read_csv(r'D:\seminar\totaldata.csv')
      2 dataset.head()

Comment: Or use `pathlib`, yes. There are multiple solutions, I was just pointing out the quickest.

Comment: @lukeDeLuccia: could you please let me know how to use pathlib. i am new to python

Comment: @Priya sounds a problem with the file encoding

Comment: @Slam :  when i tried seeing the conetnt, it gives me: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @anky: it doesnt work. tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information I have gathered in the comments, seems like an encoding issue.

you can find the encoding by first installing [`chardet`](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) followed by the below code:

```
import chardet    
rawdata = open('D:\\seminar\\totaldata.csv', 'rb').read()
result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
charenc = result['encoding']
print(charenc)
```

This will give you the encoding of the file.

Once you have the encoding, you can read as :

```
pd.read_csv('D:\\seminar\\totaldata.csv',encoding = 'encoding you found')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv(r'D:\seminar\totaldata.csv',encoding = 'encoding you found')
```

You will get the list of all encoding [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use Jupyter Notebook to read a csv file which is located on your local machine, and if you are trying to read it using the relative path of the csv file, you might find using the full file path for the csv file will fix the error and allow pandas to read the file. I had a similar problem and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the full path location from the top of the folder and paste it in the **pd.read_csv(`.....`)**
This worked for me.

Comment: Hello Faiz, this question already has an answer (green mark). You must understand the issue at hand and. In this case, you assumed the op failed to copy a path, but the issue stemmed from the character "\" being used as an escape character ("\n", "\t" for next line and tabulation, respectively).  Also, it would be best if you tried to enquire (comments bellow question) before answering.

Answer (score 0):

late in party.

If you are trying to use Jupyter Notebook to read a csv file which is located on your local machine, and if you are trying to read it using the relative path of the csv file, then it will change relative path with Current Working Directory + your File Parameter[FileName]

Because Jupyter Notebook automatically append Default path if you are not using full path [Absolute path] like

(Note: suppose Jupyter Default path is

'C:\Users\ersar\Desktop'  # To get current Working directory first check by using

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Now suppose you supplies as

```
companies = pd.read_csv("companies.txt", sep="\t", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

but your file located in 'C:\Users\ersar\Desktop\Project\Company'

then it will search file in your Current Working Directory(cwd= 'C:\Users\ersar\Desktop') which will not found so it gives error.

so always give Full path not Relative path

like

```
companies = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\ersar\\Desktop\\Project\\Company\\companies.txt", sep="\t", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

**according to pandas documentation:
filepath_or_bufferstr, path object or file-like object
Any valid string path is acceptable. The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, gs, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. A local file could be: file://localhost/path/to/table.csv.
If you want to pass in a path object, pandas accepts any os.PathLike.
By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.**

Answer (score -1):

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\seminar\\totaldata.csv')  
dataset.head()
```

Escaping the special characters(Here \t is special character for tab) in the string using a backslash might help.

You can use raw string instead which would automatically treat back slash as literal character instead of treating it as escape character.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'D:\seminar\totaldata.csv')  
dataset.head()
```